# Как измерить размер потока данных из интернета?

Tags: c#, uwp, потоки-данных

```
Stream stream = await cli.GetStreamAsync(files.href);
var FileStream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
await stream.CopyToAsync(FileStream);
await FileStream.FlushAsync();
```

Мне нужно измерить объем скачанной информации в текущий момент времени(хочу сделать индикатор в процентах).

Comment: Если речь идёт о скачивании файлов, то можно воспользоваться классом WebClient. Он качает файлы асинхронно и у него есть событие прогресса скачивания.

Comment: В UWP WebClient заменен HttpClient, который так просто файлы не качает((

Comment: Сервер не обязан сообщать конечный размер файла, так что проценты получатся не для всех.

Comment: в том-то и дело я знаю конечный размер файлов которые качаю. Мне нужно узнать количество скачанной инфы.

Comment: @Сергей тогда вместо CopyToAsync надо циклом копировать

Comment: @Сергей: _так просто файлы не качает_ — неужели скопировать стрим в файл так сложно? Вы ж программист.

Comment: @VladD скопировать в файл не проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте я объясню, что имел в виду @Pavel Mayorov.

Когда вы получаете поток, вы не должны копировать его одним махом через `CopyToAsync`, потому что вы не получаете информации о протекании операции. Поэтому вам нужно организовать копирование между потоками вручную.

Маленькая подробность: если мы сразу получаем поток, то у нас не выйдет узнать размер файла. Поэтому возьмём не поток, а весь `HttpResponseMessage`, а из него уж получим и размер, и `Stream`.

Получаем вот такой код:

```
static async Task DownloadWithProgress(HttpClient c, Uri uri, string savePath,
                                        IProgress<(long downloaded, long? total)> progress)
{
    // получаем http-ответ
    using (var resp = await c.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        // проверяем успешность запроса
        if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Download failed: {resp.ReasonPhrase}");
        using (var content = resp.Content)
        {
            // запрашиваем длину
            var total = content.Headers.ContentLength;
            // получаем потоки
            using (var instr = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var outstr = File.Create(savePath))
            {
                // и копируем один в другой вручную, через буфер
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // подберите размер сами!
                long readySoFar = 0;
                progress.Report((readySoFar, total));
                while (true)
                {
                    var actuallyRead = await instr.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (actuallyRead == 0)
                        break;
                    await outstr.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, actuallyRead);
                    readySoFar += actuallyRead;
                    // оправляем отчёт о прогрессе копирования
                    progress.Report((readySoFar, total));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Для случая UWP вам придётся, вероятно, заменить `string savePath` на `IStorageFile newFile` и `File.Create(savePath)` на `await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()` (мне не на чем проверить).

Пользоваться, например, так:

```
var uri = ...;
var progress = new Progress<(long downloaded, long? total)>(p => Console.WriteLine(
    p.total.HasValue ?
        $"Downloaded {p.downloaded} ({(double)p.downloaded / p.total.Value:0.00%})" :
        $"Downloaded {p.downloaded} of ?"));
var savePath = ...;
using (var c = new HttpClient())
    await DownloadWithProgress(c, uri, savePath, progress);
```

Comment: Может быть `некак` => `никак не`? В то не очень звучит как-то...

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Хм, мне казалось, что нормальное русское слово: «Как узнать? А узнать-то и нéкак.»

Comment: Ну как бы валидное, да. Но не достаточно популярное, я думаю. В общем, вам виднее, авторский стиль и все такое :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Если оно вызывает вопросы, надо поменять, чтобы не отвлекало от ответа :)

Comment: Тут ещё может ситуация - придёт "умник", подумает опечатка, исправит и исказит тем самым смысл