# Обновление UserControl из отдельного потока

Tags: c, wpf, .net

Имеется метод, который:

```
- загружает данные;
- выполняет рассшифровку;
- выводит полученные данные на экран.
```

В этот момент на экране крутится [`progressring`](http://mahapps.com/controls/progress-ring.html), а под ним `TextBlock`, в который выводится статус выполнения.

1.Как использовать Task для выполнения перечисленного выше?
Мне посоветовали такой подход [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766517/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0). Изучив [эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0/418463#418463), узнал, что есть библиотека для `.Net 4.0` для работы с `async/await`, которая называется 
[Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

2.Как использовать данную библиотеку? И какое пространство имен нужно подключить после того, как установил ее из NuGet?

3.Как используя `Task` и `async/await` обновлять прогресс?

Answer (score 0):

Например, так. Длинную задачу оформляете в виде асинхронной функции, которая докладывает о своих результатах через `IProgress<T>`.

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767759/10105) есть пример с загрузкой (только вам нужно не в файл а в `Stream`). Точно так же оформляете и процедуру расшифровки.

Соответственно ваш код будет таким:

```
ring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Progress<double> p = new Progress<double>(v => progressBar.Value = v);
var stream = await DownloadWithProgress(uri, p);
var decrypted = await DecryptWithProgress(stream, p);
ring.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
// выводите тут данные
```

(Это отвечает на первый и третий пункты вопроса.)